# React Native asynchronous Jest component testing

Tags: javascript, react-native, asynchronous, testing, jestjs

I have a component that dispatches a `fetch` request on mount, and displays the results.

I am trying to create a test snapshot of this component **after** the request is completed. I've been banging my head at this for quite some time now, here are the related question on SO that gave me no luck:

1. [Async component snapshot using Jest and Redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42773502/async-component-snapshot-using-jest-and-redux)
2. [How do test async components with Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46718663/how-do-test-async-components-with-jest)
3. [React+Jest - Testing async components and waiting for mount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50667197/reactjest-testing-async-components-and-waiting-for-mount)
4. [How to take a jest snapshot after axios fetched data in componentDidMount?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545881/how-to-take-a-jest-snapshot-after-axios-fetched-data-in-componentdidmount)

This is my `fetch` mock:

```
// Mocking the global.fetch included in React Native
global.fetch = jest.fn()

// Helper to mock a success response (only once)
fetch.mockResponseSuccess = (body, status = 200) => {
    fetch.mockImplementationOnce(() =>
        Promise.resolve({
            status,
            json: () => Promise.resolve(JSON.parse(body))
        })
    )
}

// Helper to mock a failure response (only once)
fetch.mockResponseFailure = error => {
    fetch.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.reject(error))
}
```

The component (simplified):

```
export class Posts extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            items: [],
            loading: false
        }
        this._getItems()
    }

    async _getItems() {
        const resp = await fetch(
                "/user/recent_posts",
                {
                    method: "GET"
                }
            )
        this.setState({
            items: resp.json["data"],
        })
    }

    render() {
        // renders this.state.items
    }
```

This is the test:

```
    test("view renders correctly", async done => {
        fetch.mockResponseSuccess(
            JSON.stringify({
                data: [
                    { caption: "test", likes: 100 },
                    { caption: "test2", likes: 200 }
                ]
            })
        )
        // also tried with setTimeout and setImidiate
        const wrapper = await shallow(<Posts />) // also tried with react-test-renderer
        await wrapper.update() // didn't work with or without
        // await waitForState(wrapper, state => state.loading === false) --> didn't work
        // process.nextTick(() => {.... --> didn't work
        // jest.runTimersToTime(1) --> didn't work
        expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()
        done()
    })
```

The problem is that `this.state.items` in the snapshot is always empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, here is what solved it for me:

```
test("view renders correctly", done => {
    // mock response here...
    const wrapper = shallow(<Posts />)
    setImmediate(() => {
        wrapper.update()
        try {
            expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }

        done()
    })
})
```

Comment: Same problem here, but I don't understand your solution :(